# override firefox forms.css

Tags: html, css, firefox

i have a problem styling html `<select>` element.

After work around, i found the problem  that firefox always overrride css with forms.css in every page load.

my question is how to override firefox default css in my page ?

Comment: Are you including styles for the select in your stylesheet?

Comment: i have write a css style: `select { font-size: 8px }` and included in my html page, but the `<select>` font size not change.

Answer (score 0):

forms.css, I am assuming this is your style sheet.

I am also guessing that this has some very specific styles that are more specific than select{}

Use firebug to determine what styles are being applied and where they are coming from, will at least show you if your style is being overridden.

Comment: it's firefox's default styling of forms

Comment: forms.css is a Firefox user agent stylesheet: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/forms.css

Comment: Using Firebug is probably the best option. I always specify a font-size for the select element with no problems, so it's likely your style is being overridden by something with higher specificity somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a pseudo class for the element like

```
select.my_select1 { font-size: 8px; }
```

Then apply the pseudo class the element with

```
<select class="my_select1">
```

Looking at a web app that I'm building now that displays perfectly in all current major browsers, I have assigned pseudo classes to each of these form elements and have no problem.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem.  I made a custom style select but the option:checked was getting a style from the Firefox forms.css that I could not override.

My co-workers found two solutions:

1. -webkit-text-fill-color: myColor; // on the select
2. select:focus:-moz-focusring {color: myColor;} // on the select